# Navigate between text fields using javascript and two arrows icons

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to make 2 arrows (Up & Down buttons).  Both are .gif. the thing is:

I have form with 4 text fields. How do I make it so that when I click the Down button.gif I navigate to the next text field then if press again I navigate to another field, and if I press Up button.gif to navigate up to the previous field like with a keyboard using arrows but instead using 2 images up & down.

How have to be the javascript function for this?

Comment: Are you trying to move the cursor inside of a `textarea`, or are you trying to select the next `input` inside of a `form` and give it focus?

Comment: i already have this scheme: client can click text input then it focus and write something then select another text input focus then write another thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the attribute `tabindex` to the different input fields you can access them with `document.querySelector('input[tabindex="1"]')` (replace 1 with current field tabindex) and call `.focus()` on them.

Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/xc2n7/